# How do I open a new page from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This question is probably already answered here, but I couldn't find the answer?  Is there any way to navigate to another page in code-behind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Response.Redirect("path_to/newpage.aspx");`

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Response.Redirect, you can also use Server.Transfer("~/path_to/newpage.aspx"), which is useful when you want to display a different page to the user without the URL in the browser changing.

Answer (score 0):

by using

1) [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309.aspx)("path");

2)[Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800.aspx)("path");